# Get row numbers for each group of records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table like this:

```
Time   Id    Item   Size
=====  ===== ====== ====
09:15  3128  TC8991 40
09:15  3128  RD4453 20
09:15  3128  DE5874 30
10:21  2574  RF5544 40
10:21  2574  WS4441 25
11:33  3369  TG4987 30
11:58  7413  HG4539 40
```

I need to put a row number for each combination of Time + Id, like this:

```
Row  Time   Id    Item   Size
==== =====  ===== ====== ====
1    09:15  3128  TC8991 40
2    09:15  3128  RD4453 20
3    09:15  3128  DE5874 30
1    10:21  2574  RF5544 40
2    10:21  2574  WS4441 25
1    11:33  3369  TG4987 30
1    11:58  7413  HG4539 40
```

My query is like this:

```
select time, id, item, size
from transactions
```

Any ideas?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach in MySQL is to use variables:

```
select time, id, item, size,
       (@rn := if(@ti = concat(time, id), @rn + 1,
                  if(@ti := concat(time, id), 1, 1)
                 )
       ) as row
from transactions cross join
     (select @rn := 0, @ti := '')
order by time, id;
```